# Extracting lowercased russian words from UTF8 text

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, text-extraction, utf

Using ActiveState Perl 5.14.2 on Windows 7 or Perl 5.10.1 on CentOS 6.3 Linux I am trying to extract all lowercased words from an UTF8 text:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

while(<>) {
    # print "$1\n" while /\b([a-z]{3,})\b/g;
    print "$1\n" while /\b([\x{0430}-\x{044F}]{3,})\b/g;
}
```

While this works well for english words (see the commented line above), this fails for cyrillic ones (please see [the Unicode range chart](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0400.pdf)) - nothing is printed by the script.

Does anybody please know, what is wrong?

A sample russian text is pasted below for your convenience:

> Все смешалось в доме Облонских. Жена узнала, что муж был в связи с
>   бывшею в их доме француженкою-гувернанткой, и объявила мужу, что не
>   может жить с ним в одном доме. Положение это продолжалось уже третий
>   день и мучительно чувствовалось и самими супругами, и всеми членами
>   семьи, и домочадцами.

Comment: What about using `\p{Cyrillic}` and `\p{Lowercase_Letter}` instead of the range?

Comment: Yes, I've read about `\p{Cyrillic}` - but would like to extract fully lowercased words only (i.e. not the 1st and not the 5th word in my sample text). I'm not sure how to do it here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You referring for ranges >255 (`\x{0430}`), which is internal Perl unicode format. But your strings seems is not converted into that format. You need to setup `use utf8;` pragma. This works for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8"); #Fix stdout warning

while(<DATA>) {
    print lc($1)."\n" while /\b([\x{0430}-\x{044F}]{3,})\b/g;
}
__DATA__
Все смешалось в доме Облонских. Жена узнала, что муж был.
в связи с бывшею в их доме француженкою-гувернанткой, и объявила мужу, что не может жить с ним в одном доме.
Положение это продолжалось уже третий день и мучительно чувствовалось и самими супругами, и всеми членами семьи, и домочадцами.
```

But is more correct way is to operate characters, not ranges. Also, if you reading from some file you maybe need to setup utf8 flag:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

while(<>) {
    utf8::decode($_); #Convert into internal utf8 format
    print lc($1)."\n" while /\b([а-яА-ЯёЁ]{3,})\b/g;
}
```

Файл:

```
Однажды в студёную зимнуюю пору... ёёёёЁЁЁ йййЙЙЙЙ
Приветт, земляк!
```

If you enable `use utf8` **lc()** will know to to lowercase letters.

(`ёЁ` is separated cus it is umlaut and not fit into range)

Comment: Hmm, with `__DATA__` it works well, but not with separate .txt files? Should I `binmode(ARGV, ':utf8')` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your STDIN and STDOUT to UTF-8:

```
binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';
binmode STDIN, ':utf8';
```

Your regex should work after this.

That said, I would use a combination of Unicode property tests instead of an explicit range:

```
\b(((?=\p{Cyrillic})\p{Lowercase_Letter}){3,})\b
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work - nothing is printed. Neither on Windows, nor on Linux (while editing UTF8 texts in Vim works ok).

Comment: Sorry `\b(((?=\p{Cyrillic})\p{Lowercase_Letter}){3,})\b` does not work event with `utf8::decode($_);` applied: same russian word is printed again and again.